# Pandas Interpolate (quadratic) not extrapolating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to extrapolate my dataset. I can extrapolate using spline methods, however using the quadratic method, it does not extrapolate, leaving NaNs.
Similarly "Linear" just copies cell values, which I was expecting from "nearest" method.

Dataset:

```
Id Current Injected (RMS) [A]   -355.6   -330.2     -304.8     -279.4     -254.0     -228.6     -203.2     -177.8     -152.4     -127.0     -101.6     -76.2      -50.8      -25.4       0.0
Iq Current Injected (RMS) [A]
0.0                            -0.0475  -0.0525  -0.165000  -0.307500  -0.250000  -0.320000  -0.362500  -0.432500  -0.625000  -0.672500  -0.567500  -0.570000  -0.642500  -0.560000  -0.497500
25.4                            6.3475   6.2325   6.227500   6.072500   5.962500   5.877500   5.697500   5.602500   5.357500   5.080000   4.815000   4.727500   4.497500   4.195000   3.767500
50.8                           12.7600  12.7075  12.787500  12.490000  12.395000  12.062500  11.782500  11.585000  11.332500  11.080000  10.635000  10.330000  10.092500   9.527500   8.632500
76.2                               NaN  19.1825  19.062500  18.880001  18.792500  18.522501  18.137501  17.890001  17.410000  17.087500  16.635001  16.425000  15.802500  14.752500  13.497500
101.6                              NaN  25.0475  24.967500  24.805000  24.592501  24.287500  23.932501  23.457501  23.062501  22.710001  22.350000  21.825000  20.760001  19.232501  17.725001
127.0                              NaN  29.8200  29.787500  29.732500  29.490000  29.110000  28.782501  28.350001  27.770000  27.372501  26.745000  25.592500  24.157500  21.645000  21.607500
152.4                              NaN      NaN  34.935001  34.897500  34.827501  34.357500  34.065001  33.500000  32.957501  32.195000  31.320000  29.905000  28.102500  26.040000  24.260001
177.8                              NaN      NaN  39.032501  39.095001  38.995000  38.740000  38.262500  37.700000  37.112500  36.160001  34.855001  33.332500  31.210001  29.082500  27.452501
203.2                              NaN      NaN        NaN  42.687501  42.457501  42.190001  41.655001  41.105002  40.240000  39.285000  37.825001  36.040000  33.980001  31.895001  30.240001
228.6                              NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN  43.997501  43.590001  43.142501  42.335001  41.427501  40.265001  38.717500  37.025001  34.920000  33.762500  32.777501
254.0                              NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN  46.560001  46.030001  45.455000  44.677501  43.775001  42.515001  41.000001  39.330001  37.270001  35.307501  33.860000
279.4                              NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  47.112501  46.442500  45.570001  44.437500  42.842501  41.167501  39.390001  37.420001  36.032501
304.8                              NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  48.052501  44.547501  45.817501  44.545001  43.000000  41.210001  39.297500  37.852501
330.2                              NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  47.422501  45.910001  44.430000  42.642501  40.687501  39.375000
355.6                              NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  42.447501  41.110001
```

Quadratic returns the same.

```
        report_df["Data"]["Interpolated"]["Torque Measured [Nm]"].interpolate(
            method="quadratic", inplace=True, limit_area=None, limit_direction="both"
        )
```

Linear:

```
        report_df["Data"]["Interpolated"]["Torque Measured [Nm]"].interpolate(
            method="linear", inplace=True, limit_area=None, limit_direction="both"
        )
```

```
Id Current Injected (RMS) [A]   -355.6   -330.2     -304.8     -279.4     -254.0     -228.6     -203.2     -177.8     -152.4     -127.0     -101.6     -76.2      -50.8      -25.4       0.0
Iq Current Injected (RMS) [A]
0.0                            -0.0475  -0.0525  -0.165000  -0.307500  -0.250000  -0.320000  -0.362500  -0.432500  -0.625000  -0.672500  -0.567500  -0.570000  -0.642500  -0.560000  -0.497500
25.4                            6.3475   6.2325   6.227500   6.072500   5.962500   5.877500   5.697500   5.602500   5.357500   5.080000   4.815000   4.727500   4.497500   4.195000   3.767500
50.8                           12.7600  12.7075  12.787500  12.490000  12.395000  12.062500  11.782500  11.585000  11.332500  11.080000  10.635000  10.330000  10.092500   9.527500   8.632500
76.2                           12.7600  19.1825  19.062500  18.880001  18.792500  18.522501  18.137501  17.890001  17.410000  17.087500  16.635001  16.425000  15.802500  14.752500  13.497500
101.6                          12.7600  25.0475  24.967500  24.805000  24.592501  24.287500  23.932501  23.457501  23.062501  22.710001  22.350000  21.825000  20.760001  19.232501  17.725001
127.0                          12.7600  29.8200  29.787500  29.732500  29.490000  29.110000  28.782501  28.350001  27.770000  27.372501  26.745000  25.592500  24.157500  21.645000  21.607500
152.4                          12.7600  29.8200  34.935001  34.897500  34.827501  34.357500  34.065001  33.500000  32.957501  32.195000  31.320000  29.905000  28.102500  26.040000  24.260001
177.8                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  39.095001  38.995000  38.740000  38.262500  37.700000  37.112500  36.160001  34.855001  33.332500  31.210001  29.082500  27.452501
203.2                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  42.457501  42.190001  41.655001  41.105002  40.240000  39.285000  37.825001  36.040000  33.980001  31.895001  30.240001
228.6                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  43.997501  43.590001  43.142501  42.335001  41.427501  40.265001  38.717500  37.025001  34.920000  33.762500  32.777501
254.0                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  46.560001  46.030001  45.455000  44.677501  43.775001  42.515001  41.000001  39.330001  37.270001  35.307501  33.860000
279.4                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  46.560001  46.030001  47.112501  46.442500  45.570001  44.437500  42.842501  41.167501  39.390001  37.420001  36.032501
304.8                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  46.560001  46.030001  47.112501  48.052501  44.547501  45.817501  44.545001  43.000000  41.210001  39.297500  37.852501
330.2                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  46.560001  46.030001  47.112501  48.052501  44.547501  47.422501  45.910001  44.430000  42.642501  40.687501  39.375000
355.6                          12.7600  29.8200  39.032501  42.687501  46.560001  46.030001  47.112501  48.052501  44.547501  47.422501  45.910001  44.430000  42.642501  42.447501  41.110001
```

Spline:

```
        report_df["Data"]["Interpolated"]["Torque Measured [Nm]"].interpolate(
            method="spline", order=1, inplace=True, limit_area=None, limit_direction="both"
        )
```

```
Id Current Injected (RMS) [A]     -355.6     -330.2     -304.8     -279.4     -254.0     -228.6     -203.2     -177.8     -152.4     -127.0     -101.6     -76.2      -50.8      -25.4       0.0
Iq Current Injected (RMS) [A]
0.0                            -0.047500  -0.052500  -0.165000  -0.307500  -0.250000  -0.320000  -0.362500  -0.432500  -0.625000  -0.672500  -0.567500  -0.570000  -0.642500  -0.560000  -0.497500
25.4                            6.347500   6.232500   6.227500   6.072500   5.962500   5.877500   5.697500   5.602500   5.357500   5.080000   4.815000   4.727500   4.497500   4.195000   3.767500
50.8                           12.760000  12.707500  12.787500  12.490000  12.395000  12.062500  11.782500  11.585000  11.332500  11.080000  10.635000  10.330000  10.092500   9.527500   8.632500
76.2                           19.160833  19.182500  19.062500  18.880001  18.792500  18.522501  18.137501  17.890001  17.410000  17.087500  16.635001  16.425000  15.802500  14.752500  13.497500
101.6                          25.564583  25.047500  24.967500  24.805000  24.592501  24.287500  23.932501  23.457501  23.062501  22.710001  22.350000  21.825000  20.760001  19.232501  17.725001
127.0                          31.968333  29.820000  29.787500  29.732500  29.490000  29.110000  28.782501  28.350001  27.770000  27.372501  26.745000  25.592500  24.157500  21.645000  21.607500
152.4                          38.372084  36.717834  34.935001  34.897500  34.827501  34.357500  34.065001  33.500000  32.957501  32.195000  31.320000  29.905000  28.102500  26.040000  24.260001
177.8                          44.775834  42.783048  39.032501  39.095001  38.995000  38.740000  38.262500  37.700000  37.112500  36.160001  34.855001  33.332500  31.210001  29.082500  27.452501
203.2                          51.179584  48.848263  46.266430  42.687501  42.457501  42.190001  41.655001  41.105002  40.240000  39.285000  37.825001  36.040000  33.980001  31.895001  30.240001
228.6                          57.583334  54.913477  51.919109  49.756115  43.997501  43.590001  43.142501  42.335001  41.427501  40.265001  38.717500  37.025001  34.920000  33.762500  32.777501
254.0                          63.987084  60.978691  57.571787  54.978017  46.560001  46.030001  45.455000  44.677501  43.775001  42.515001  41.000001  39.330001  37.270001  35.307501  33.860000
279.4                          70.390834  67.043906  63.224466  60.199918  52.119290  51.509905  47.112501  46.442500  45.570001  44.437500  42.842501  41.167501  39.390001  37.420001  36.032501
304.8                          76.794584  73.109120  68.877145  65.421819  55.779294  55.104131  52.116468  48.052501  44.547501  45.817501  44.545001  43.000000  41.210001  39.297500  37.852501
330.2                          83.198334  79.174335  74.529824  70.643720  59.439298  58.698357  55.131041  52.677491  48.403590  47.422501  45.910001  44.430000  42.642501  40.687501  39.375000
355.6                          89.602084  85.239549  80.182502  75.865622  63.099302  62.292582  58.145613  55.381840  50.002117  50.785235  48.978943  47.126564  45.099283  42.447501  41.110001
```

Comment: First you need to make sure if your column dtypes are floats. If that's true, try adding `axis=1` parameter to your linear method attempt. I tried reproducing your attempts with that and it worked.